# Longest and Shortest day of the year in all planets

Tags: planet, solar-system

Can we trace the longest and shortest day of the year in other planets of Solar system similar to earth planet i.e. Mars, Saturn, Venus, Jupiter, Mercury, Neptune, Uranus?

Comment: 1. Salutations are not required here 2. Pluto is not a planet

Comment: Finding where the equinoxes are in the orbit is pretty straightforward, but the biggest problem is what calendar to use.

Comment: Especially when looking at planets which have a small number of solar days per year. Venus gets a shade under two per orbit, and a solar day on Mercury is twice the length of its orbital period.